# Debezium `source.lsn` field value in snapshot records(when `__op=r`)

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, wal

I can't find an information in Debezium Postgresql connector config [documentation page](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html) regarding the `source.lsn` field value for snapshot events(events having `__op=r`). I've ran a test on my dev environment database, which doesn't have much load, and I have got **non-null** `lsn` value for all events having `__op=r`. As my db doesn't have much load I assume that all WAL segments created from the beginning are still present, though not sure about that.

My questions are the following:

1. How does debezium get a non-null `lsn` value for snapshot records if it just gets that records' info by issuing `select` queries on all existing data(in contrast of checking the WAL for generating events having `__op=c` or `__op=u` or `__op=d`) ? Is the WAL anyway checked during snapshotting ?
2. Assuming that the WAL is checked during snapshotting, what will be the value of `lsn` in snapshot event in case if the corresponding WAL segment is already deleted ? Is `lsn` equal to `null` in such case ?
3. Is there any documentation from Debezium describing the possible `lsn` values in case of snapshotting ?

Answer (score 0):

> How does debezium get a non-null `lsn`

The `source.lsn` value for a new snapshot is sourced from the `consistent_point` that available via the newly created replication slot when the connector began.  This makes sense as its the point when the slot was created and the timepoint in which the exported snapshot is taken.

> what will be the value of `lsn` in snapshot event in case if the corresponding WAL segment is already deleted ? Is `lsn` equal to null in such case ?

When a replication slot is created and there are entries in the WAL that are pending delivery to the consumer of the replication slot, WAL segments cannot be freed until PG says they're no longer needed.  AFAIK, you cannot achieve the state you described.

> Is there any documentation from Debezium describing the possible lsn values in case of snapshotting ?

We don't cover this in the documentation but it should be possible to see by querying the replication slot while a snapshot is happening and seeing the starting LSN value is identical to that of the records in the snapshot.

Comment: Please clarify the following: The `Snapshots` section in Debezium postgresql connector's doc says that when we start the connector with `snapshot.mode=initial`, PostgreSQL connector most probably would be unable to see the entire history of the database by reading only the WAL as most PostgreSQL servers are configured to not retain the complete history of the database in the WAL segments. That's why it starts a transaction and reads the table records in consistent snapshot creating `__op=r` events from table rows. So if WAL is already deleted for row X how `lsm` gets a non-null value for X?

Comment: The question is about the case when there is a table having some amount of rows created very far ago, and the WAL, storing the log for those records' creation/updates is already deleted at the moment when the replication slot is created. Connector performs initial snapshot, creates events with `__op=r` gets the event payload just by reading the table record, but how connector populates the `lsn` field for that event if WAL is not available anymore ? Shouldn't `lsn` be NULL in that case ?

Comment: No, the LSN is associated with the point in time in which the snapshot export is started; not when the original row was added to the table.